# How to make batch analysis for list with apply family

Tags: r

I have been trying to make batch univariate cox analysis with apply family and for loops, but I can't edit useful and effective codes. Please, please help me!

I have prepared two kinds of data. Data A, "data_train_list" is a list comprising many data frames. And each column elements in every data frame will serve as independent variables in my codes. Data B, "os_train_list" also is a list including data with data frames. And each data frame in this list will serve as the response variable.

Here are my codes,

```
for (i in 1:length(data_train_list)) {comb_resBM[[i]]=apply(data_train_list[[i]],2,FUN = function(x){
  coxph(Surv(os_train_list[[i]]$time,os_train_list[[i]]$status)~.,data = data_train_list[[i]] )
})}
```

I hope finally codes can analyze correctly and effectively, because the data in the analysis is huge actually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this would work

```
library(survival)
outLst <- Map(function(x, y) {
               coxph(with(y, Surv(time, status))~ ., data = y)
                 }, data_train_list, os_train_list)
```

Comment: Yes, I accepted your answer just now, and sorry for I can't vote it because of my low reputation.

Comment: And there is another problem for me. I checked the output result, "outList". But I didn't find p.value to each factor in Y. How can I get it?

Comment: @MinWu It's okay.  Glad to know that the code works for you

Comment: @MinWu For that you may needd to wrap with `summary` i..e `summary(coxph(....))$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"]`

Comment: Sorry, I have used the summary function, but it shows the same output of "outList". Another, the result of  summary(coxph(....))$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"] is NULL.

Comment: @MinWu  I meant `summary(coxph(with(y, Surv(time, status))~ ., data = y))$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"]`

Comment: Yes,do you mean like this?    But they indeed show NULL.                                                                                                                                        > outLst <- Map(function(x, y) {
+   summary(coxph(with(y, Surv(time, status))~ ., data = y))$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"] 
+ }, data_train_list, os_train_list)
> View(outLst)
> outLst[[1]]
NULL

Comment: @MinWu What is the output of `summary` without the `$coefficients` part.  Also check the `str`